# The probability of a Poissonian event affected by Bernoulli

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I’ve managed to get the correct answer to this question but I really doubt if I actually solved it or just stumbled upon the solution.

> The Question: a certain fridge has one cookie in it, the number of people opening the fridge during the day is poissonian with parameter $\lambda = 6$. If a person opens the fridge and the cookie is uneaten, he’ll eat it with probability $p=\tfrac23$. What’s the probability 3 people opened the fridge if the cookie is known to be uneaten?

Now I’ve tried solving it with Bayes’ rule but was unable to compute $P(\text{cookie remains uneaten})$ so I abandoned it in favor of something I remembered.

 A poissonian distribution affected by an independent event with probability p is distributed as $p_X(k) =  e^{-\lambda p } \frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!}$ so if I choose $p=\tfrac13$ I might be able to say that probability of 3 people coming to the fridge and choosing not to eat the cookie is $$p_X(3) = e^{-1/3 \cdot 6} \cdot \frac{2^3}{3!}= \frac43e^{-2}$$ which is the correct answer.
I’m unsure if my calculation is correct, when is this modification applicable  and what’s the justification for this, and if it’s not how am I supposed to approach this question?

Comment: The question wants you tho think that the composition of the two events is like a poisson random variable with rate $6 \times \frac{2}{3} = 4,$ and they are asking $P(X \geq 3)$ (although, they may also mean $P(X = 3)$ as the wording is ambiguous).

Comment: is what I did wrong in that regard? the thing that bothers me most is the lack of beyes

Comment: I tried to formalise this exercise and I'm missing the time that has elapsed. In fact, a Poisson process has a rate which is exactly that # of unites per unit of measure (in your case, measure is time). So to say that $\lambda = 6$ is rather meaningless. If the question said that $\lambda = 6 p/hr$ then they could ask "After 1 hour, it is known the cookie is uneaten, what is the probabability that (exactly) 3 people opened the fridge?" The reason is that this forces the random variable to be Poisson of parameter 6, if it had been two hours, the parameter would be 12, etc.

Comment: it’s the number of people who open the fridge during the day - I’m sorry I must’ve accidentally omitted that detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the solution you've arrived at, however if you want a solution utilizing Bayes' theorem, here is one:

Let $\mathsf{N}$ denote the number of people opening the fridge, i.e. $\mathsf{N}\sim \mathrm{Poisson}(6)$ and let $A$ be the event that the cookie remains uneaten.
By your description, you've probably found that
$$
 \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{N}=3\mid A)
 =\frac{\mathbb{P}(A\mid \mathsf{N}=3)\cdot\mathbb{P}(\mathsf{N}=3)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}
 =\frac{\frac{1}{3^3}\cdot\frac{6^3\mathrm{e}^{-6}}{3!}}{\mathbb{P}(A)},
$$
and the tricky part is now finding $\mathbb{P}(A)$.
One useful trick is using the law of total probability.
Indeed, using this we find that
$$
 \mathbb{P}(A)
 =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(A\mid \mathsf{N}=n)\cdot \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{N}=n)
 =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n}\cdot\frac{6^n\mathrm{e}^{-6}}{n!}
 =\mathrm{e}^{-6}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{n!}
 =\mathrm{e}^{-6}\cdot \mathrm{e}^{2}.
$$
Plugging this back into the above, we find that
$$
 \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{N}=3\mid A)
 =\frac{\frac{1}{3^3}\cdot\frac{6^3\mathrm{e}^{-6}}{3!}}{\mathrm{e}^{-6}\cdot\mathrm{e}^{2}}
 =\frac{4}{3}\mathrm{e}^{-2}.
$$